# Graphviz dot and Doxygen does not generate UML diagrams

Tags: uml, codeblocks, doxygen, graphviz, dot

I have Graphviz dot set up correctly with `dot.exe` configured correctly in Doxygen. However, the html output does not contain any UML diagrams. There were no errors during Run too.

Below are my settings, did I miss anything out? Thank you.

```
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Configuration options related to the dot tool
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
CLASS_DIAGRAMS         = YES
DIA_PATH               =
HIDE_UNDOC_RELATIONS   = YES
HAVE_DOT               = YES
DOT_NUM_THREADS        = 0
DOT_FONTNAME           = Helvetica
DOT_FONTSIZE           = 10
DOT_FONTPATH           =
CLASS_GRAPH            = YES
COLLABORATION_GRAPH    = YES
GROUP_GRAPHS           = YES
UML_LOOK               = YES
UML_LIMIT_NUM_FIELDS   = 99
TEMPLATE_RELATIONS     = YES
INCLUDE_GRAPH          = YES
INCLUDED_BY_GRAPH      = YES
CALL_GRAPH             = YES
CALLER_GRAPH           = YES
GRAPHICAL_HIERARCHY    = YES
DIRECTORY_GRAPH        = YES
DOT_IMAGE_FORMAT       = jpg
INTERACTIVE_SVG        = YES
DOT_PATH               = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz2.38\bin"
DOTFILE_DIRS           =
MSCFILE_DIRS           =
DIAFILE_DIRS           =
PLANTUML_JAR_PATH      =
PLANTUML_CFG_FILE      =
PLANTUML_INCLUDE_PATH  =
DOT_GRAPH_MAX_NODES    = 999
MAX_DOT_GRAPH_DEPTH    = 999
DOT_TRANSPARENT        = YES
DOT_MULTI_TARGETS      = YES
GENERATE_LEGEND        = YES
DOT_CLEANUP            = NO
```

[image]

---

Log File:

```
Searching for include files...
Searching for example files...
Searching for images...
Searching for dot files...
Searching for msc files...
Searching for dia files...
Searching for files to exclude
Searching INPUT for files to process...
Searching for files in directory C:/Users/User1/Desktop/Latest Code/topic_4
Reading and parsing tag files
Parsing files
Preprocessing C:/Users/User1/Desktop/Latest Code/topic_4/Date.cpp...
Parsing file C:/Users/User1/Desktop/Latest Code/topic_4/Date.cpp...
Preprocessing C:/Users/User1/Desktop/Latest Code/topic_4/Date.h...
Parsing file C:/Users/User1/Desktop/Latest Code/topic_4/Date.h...
Preprocessing C:/Users/User1/Desktop/Latest Code/topic_4/MAIN.CPP...
Parsing file C:/Users/User1/Desktop/Latest Code/topic_4/MAIN.CPP...
Preprocessing C:/Users/User1/Desktop/Latest Code/topic_4/REGIST.CPP...
Parsing file C:/Users/User1/Desktop/Latest Code/topic_4/REGIST.CPP...
Preprocessing C:/Users/User1/Desktop/Latest Code/topic_4/REGIST.H...
Parsing file C:/Users/User1/Desktop/Latest Code/topic_4/REGIST.H...
Preprocessing C:/Users/User1/Desktop/Latest Code/topic_4/Result.cpp...
Parsing file C:/Users/User1/Desktop/Latest Code/topic_4/Result.cpp...
Preprocessing C:/Users/User1/Desktop/Latest Code/topic_4/Result.h...
Parsing file C:/Users/User1/Desktop/Latest Code/topic_4/Result.h...
Preprocessing C:/Users/User1/Desktop/Latest Code/topic_4/Unit.cpp...
Parsing file C:/Users/User1/Desktop/Latest Code/topic_4/Unit.cpp...
Preprocessing C:/Users/User1/Desktop/Latest Code/topic_4/Unit.h...
Parsing file C:/Users/User1/Desktop/Latest Code/topic_4/Unit.h...
Building group list...
Building directory list...
Building namespace list...
Building file list...
Building class list...
Computing nesting relations for classes...
Associating documentation with classes...
Building example list...
Searching for enumerations...
Searching for documented typedefs...
Searching for members imported via using declarations...
Searching for included using directives...
Searching for documented variables...
Building interface member list...
Building member list...
Searching for friends...
Searching for documented defines...
Computing class inheritance relations...
Computing class usage relations...
Flushing cached template relations that have become invalid...
Computing class relations...
Add enum values to enums...
Searching for member function documentation...
Creating members for template instances...
Building page list...
Search for main page...
Computing page relations...
Determining the scope of groups...
Sorting lists...
Determining which enums are documented
Computing member relations...
Building full member lists recursively...
Adding members to member groups.
Computing member references...
Inheriting documentation...
Generating disk names...
Adding source references...
Adding xrefitems...
Sorting member lists...
Setting anonymous enum type...
Computing dependencies between directories...
Generating citations page...
Counting members...
Counting data structures...
Resolving user defined references...
Finding anchors and sections in the documentation...
Transferring function references...
Combining using relations...
Adding members to index pages...
Correcting members for VHDL...
Generating style sheet...
Generating search indices...
Generating example documentation...
Generating file sources...
Generating code for file Date.cpp...
Generating code for file Date.h...
Generating code for file MAIN.CPP...
Generating code for file REGIST.CPP...
Generating code for file REGIST.H...
Generating code for file Result.cpp...
Generating code for file Result.h...
Generating code for file Unit.cpp...
Generating code for file Unit.h...
Generating file documentation...
Generating docs for file Date.cpp...
Generating docs for file Date.h...
Generating docs for file MAIN.CPP...
Generating call graph for function main
Generating docs for file REGIST.CPP...
Generating docs for file REGIST.H...
Generating docs for file Result.cpp...
Generating docs for file Result.h...
Generating docs for file Unit.cpp...
Generating docs for file Unit.h...
Generating page documentation...
Generating group documentation...
Generating class documentation...
Generating docs for compound Date...
Generating caller graph for function Date::GetDay
Generating caller graph for function Date::GetMonth
Generating caller graph for function Date::GetYear
Generating docs for compound Registration...
Generating caller graph for function Registration::GetCount
Generating caller graph for function Registration::GetCredits
Generating caller graph for function Registration::GetResult
Generating caller graph for function Registration::GetSemester
Generating caller graph for function Registration::GetStudentId
Generating caller graph for function Registration::SetCount
Generating caller graph for function Registration::SetResult
Generating caller graph for function Registration::SetSemester
Generating caller graph for function Registration::SetStudentId
Generating docs for compound Result...
Generating caller graph for function Result::GetDate
Generating caller graph for function Result::GetMarks
Generating caller graph for function Result::GetUnit
Generating caller graph for function Result::SetDate
Generating caller graph for function Result::SetMarks
Generating caller graph for function Result::SetUnit
Generating docs for compound Unit...
Generating caller graph for function Unit::GetCredits
Generating caller graph for function Unit::GetUnitId
Generating caller graph for function Unit::GetUnitName
Generating caller graph for function Unit::SetCredits
Generating caller graph for function Unit::SetUnitId
Generating caller graph for function Unit::SetUnitName
Generating namespace index...
Generating graph info page...
Generating directory documentation...
Generating index page...
Generating page index...
Generating module index...
Generating namespace index...
Generating namespace member index...
Generating annotated compound index...
Generating alphabetical compound index...
Generating hierarchical class index...
Generating graphical class hierarchy...
Generating member index...
Generating file index...
Generating file member index...
Generating example index...
finalizing index lists...
writing tag file...
Running plantuml with JAVA...
Running dot...
lookup cache used 156/65536 hits=737 misses=159
finished...
*** Doxygen has finished
```

---

Command: `doxygen -x Doxyfile`

```
    # Difference with default Doxyfile 1.8.17 (b5fa3cd1c6e6240e20d3b80a70e3f04040b32021*)
    EXTRACT_ALL            = YES
    EXTRACT_PRIVATE        = YES
    EXTRACT_PRIV_VIRTUAL   = YES
    EXTRACT_PACKAGE        = YES
    EXTRACT_STATIC         = YES
    EXTRACT_LOCAL_METHODS  = YES
    INPUT                  = "C:/Users/User1/Desktop/Latest Code/topic_4/"
    SOURCE_BROWSER         = YES
    INLINE_SOURCES         = YES
    REFERENCED_BY_RELATION = YES
    REFERENCES_RELATION    = YES
    HTML_TIMESTAMP         = YES
    HTML_DYNAMIC_SECTIONS  = YES
    GENERATE_LATEX         = NO
    HAVE_DOT               = YES
    UML_LOOK               = YES
    UML_LIMIT_NUM_FIELDS   = 99
    TEMPLATE_RELATIONS     = YES
    CALL_GRAPH             = YES
    CALLER_GRAPH           = YES
    DOT_IMAGE_FORMAT       = jpg
    INTERACTIVE_SVG        = YES
    DOT_PATH               = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz2.38\bin"
    DOT_GRAPH_MAX_NODES    = 999
    MAX_DOT_GRAPH_DEPTH    = 999
    DOT_TRANSPARENT        = YES
    DOT_MULTI_TARGETS      = YES
___
Command: `doxygen -d extcmd`

writing tag file...
Running plantuml with JAVA...
Running dot...
Generating dot graphs using 25 parallel threads...
... (commented out due to length)
Running dot for graph 5/43
Running dot for graph 6/43
Running dot for graph 7/43
Running dot for graph 8/43
Running dot for graph 9/43
Running dot for graph 10/43
Running dot for graph 11/43
Running dot for graph 12/43
Running dot for graph 13/43
Running dot for graph 14/43
Running dot for graph 15/43
Running dot for graph 16/43
Running dot for graph 17/43
Running dot for graph 18/43
Running dot for graph 19/43
Running dot for graph 20/43
Running dot for graph 21/43
Running dot for graph 22/43
Running dot for graph 23/43
Running dot for graph 24/43
Running dot for graph 25/43
Executing external command `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz2.38\bin\dot" "C:/Us
ers/User1/Desktop/Latest Code/topic_4/html/_r_e_g_i_s_t_8_c_p_p__incl.dot"
-Tjpg -o "C:/Users/User1/Desktop/Latest Code/topic_4/html/_r_e_g_i_s_t_8_c_
p_p__incl.jpg" -Tcmapx -o "C:/Users/User1/Desktop/Latest Code/topic_4/html/
_r_e_g_i_s_t_8_c_p_p__incl.map"`
Executing external command `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz2.38\bin\dot" "C:/Us
ers/User1/Desktop/Latest Code/topic_4/html/_date_8h__dep__incl.dot" -Tjpg -
o "C:/Users/User1/Desktop/Latest Code/topic_4/html/_date_8h__dep__incl.jpg"
 -Tcmapx -o "C:/Users/User1/Desktop/Latest Code/topic_4/html/_date_8h__dep_
_incl.map"`
Running dot for graph 26/43
Running dot for graph 27/43
Executing external command `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz2.38\bin\dot" "C:/Us
ers/User1/Desktop/Latest Code/topic_4/html/class_unit_ab1f83a3955a721e46730
773747e4e67e_icgraph.dot" -Tjpg -o "C:/Users/User1/Desktop/Latest Code/topi
c_4/html/class_unit_ab1f83a3955a721e46730773747e4e67e_icgraph.jpg" -Tcmapx -o "C
:/Users/User1/Desktop/Latest Code/topic_4/html/class_unit_ab1f83a3955a721e4
6730773747e4e67e_icgraph.map"`
Running dot for graph 28/43
Executing external command `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz2.38\bin\dot" "C:/Us
ers/User1/Desktop/Latest Code/topic_4/html/class_unit_ab6bb0c89ee8541007807
210a379ad442_icgraph.dot" -Tjpg -o "C:/Users/User1/Desktop/Latest Code/topi
c_4/html/class_unit_ab6bb0c89ee8541007807210a379ad442_icgraph.jpg" -Tcmapx -o "C
:/Users/User1/Desktop/Latest Code/topic_4/html/class_unit_ab6bb0c89ee854100
7807210a379ad442_icgraph.map"`
Running dot for graph 29/43
Executing external command `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz2.38\bin\dot" "C:/Us
ers/User1/Desktop/Latest Code/topic_4/html/class_unit__coll__graph.dot" -Tj
pg -o "C:/Users/User1/Desktop/Latest Code/topic_4/html/class_unit__coll__gr
aph.jpg" -Tcmapx -o "C:/Users/User1/Desktop/Latest Code/topic_4/html/class_
unit__coll__graph.map"`
Running dot for graph 30/43
Executing external command `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz2.38\bin\dot" "C:/Us
ers/User1/Desktop/Latest Code/topic_4/html/class_registration_a0c1de40f970e
8b6d42ee9faafd787151_icgraph.dot" -Tjpg -o "C:/Users/User1/Desktop/Latest C
ode/topic_4/html/class_registration_a0c1de40f970e8b6d42ee9faafd787151_icgraph.jp
g" -Tcmapx -o "C:/Users/User1/Desktop/Latest Code/topic_4/html/class_regist
ration_a0c1de40f970e8b6d42ee9faafd787151_icgraph.map"`
Executing external command `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz2.38\bin\dot" "C:/Us
ers/User1/Desktop/Latest Code/topic_4/html/class_result_a845c6e50d224724121
09ee3e024f4e94_icgraph.dot" -Tjpg -o "C:/Users/User1/Desktop/Latest Code/to
pic_4/html/class_result_a845c6e50d22472412109ee3e024f4e94_icgraph.jpg" -Tcmapx -
o "C:/Users/User1/Desktop/Latest Code/topic_4/html/class_result_a845c6e50d2
2472412109ee3e024f4e94_icgraph.map"`
Running dot for graph 31/43
Running dot for graph 32/43
Executing external command `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz2.38\bin\dot" "C:/Us
ers/User1/Desktop/Latest Code/topic_4/html/_result_8h__incl.dot" -Tjpg -o "
C:/Users/User1/Desktop/Latest Code/topic_4/html/_result_8h__incl.jpg" -Tcma
px -o "C:/Users/User1/Desktop/Latest Code/topic_4/html/_result_8h__incl.map
"`
Executing external command `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz2.38\bin\dot" "C:/Us
ers/User1/Desktop/Latest Code/topic_4/html/class_date_af736c26a804e047defe7
3b7f8ff27df5_icgraph.dot" -Tjpg -o "C:/Users/User1/Desktop/Latest Code/topi
c_4/html/class_date_af736c26a804e047defe73b7f8ff27df5_icgraph.jpg" -Tcmapx -o "C
:/Users/User1/Desktop/Latest Code/topic_4/html/class_date_af736c26a804e047d
efe73b7f8ff27df5_icgraph.map"`
Executing external command `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz2.38\bin\dot" "C:/Us
ers/User1/Desktop/Latest Code/topic_4/html/class_result_a984dbc50adb7dcc920
7122fd943fe4a8_icgraph.dot" -Tjpg -o "C:/Users/User1/Desktop/Latest Code/to
pic_4/html/class_result_a984dbc50adb7dcc9207122fd943fe4a8_icgraph.jpg" -Tcmapx -
o "C:/Users/User1/Desktop/Latest Code/topic_4/html/class_result_a984dbc50ad
b7dcc9207122fd943fe4a8_icgraph.map"`
Executing external command `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz2.38\bin\dot" "C:/Us
ers/User1/Desktop/Latest Code/topic_4/html/class_registration__coll__graph.
dot" -Tjpg -o "C:/Users/User1/Desktop/Latest Code/topic_4/html/class_regist
ration__coll__graph.jpg" -Tcmapx -o "C:/Users/User1/Desktop/Latest Code/top
ic_4/html/class_registration__coll__graph.map"`
Running dot for graph 33/43
Running dot for graph 34/43
Running dot for graph 35/43
Running dot for graph 36/43
Executing external command `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz2.38\bin\dot" "C:/Us
ers/User1/Desktop/Latest Code/topic_4/html/class_registration_a712bc06cc900
d45f676941c67e4d2cac_icgraph.dot" -Tjpg -o "C:/Users/User1/Desktop/Latest C
ode/topic_4/html/class_registration_a712bc06cc900d45f676941c67e4d2cac_icgraph.jp
g" -Tcmapx -o "C:/Users/User1/Desktop/Latest Code/topic_4/html/class_regist
ration_a712bc06cc900d45f676941c67e4d2cac_icgraph.map"`
Executing external command `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz2.38\bin\dot" "C:/Us
ers/User1/Desktop/Latest Code/topic_4/html/class_registration_aa9826f4d22d5
4d33cde356bd2a82d3d7_icgraph.dot" -Tjpg -o "C:/Users/User1/Desktop/Latest C
ode/topic_4/html/class_registration_aa9826f4d22d54d33cde356bd2a82d3d7_icgraph.jp
g" -Tcmapx -o "C:/Users/User1/Desktop/Latest Code/topic_4/html/class_regist
ration_aa9826f4d22d54d33cde356bd2a82d3d7_icgraph.map"`
Executing external command `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz2.38\bin\dot" "C:/Us
ers/User1/Desktop/Latest Code/topic_4/html/class_result_a5ab5a5005e4ca9b2f0
0ab466c432abfd_icgraph.dot" -Tjpg -o "C:/Users/User1/Desktop/Latest Code/to
pic_4/html/class_result_a5ab5a5005e4ca9b2f00ab466c432abfd_icgraph.jpg" -Tcmapx -
o "C:/Users/User1/Desktop/Latest Code/topic_4/html/class_result_a5ab5a5005e
4ca9b2f00ab466c432abfd_icgraph.map"`
Executing external command `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz2.38\bin\dot" "C:/Us
ers/User1/Desktop/Latest Code/topic_4/html/_result_8h__dep__incl.dot" -Tjpg
 -o "C:/Users/User1/Desktop/Latest Code/topic_4/html/_result_8h__dep__incl.
jpg" -Tcmapx -o "C:/Users/User1/Desktop/Latest Code/topic_4/html/_result_8h
__dep__incl.map"`
Running dot for graph 37/43
Running dot for graph 38/43
Running dot for graph 39/43
Running dot for graph 40/43
Executing external command `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz2.38\bin\dot" "C:/Us
ers/User1/Desktop/Latest Code/topic_4/html/_r_e_g_i_s_t_8_h__dep__incl.dot"
 -Tjpg -o "C:/Users/User1/Desktop/Latest Code/topic_4/html/_r_e_g_i_s_t_8_h
__dep__incl.jpg" -Tcmapx -o "C:/Users/User1/Desktop/Latest Code/topic_4/htm
l/_r_e_g_i_s_t_8_h__dep__incl.map"`
Executing external command `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz2.38\bin\dot" "C:/Us
ers/User1/Desktop/Latest Code/topic_4/html/class_registration_affa3d2b34daf
b9d2c909790087e50c36_icgraph.dot" -Tjpg -o "C:/Users/User1/Desktop/Latest C
ode/topic_4/html/class_registration_affa3d2b34dafb9d2c909790087e50c36_icgraph.jp
g" -Tcmapx -o "C:/Users/User1/Desktop/Latest Code/topic_4/html/class_regist
ration_affa3d2b34dafb9d2c909790087e50c36_icgraph.map"`
Executing external command `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz2.38\bin\dot" "C:/Us
ers/User1/Desktop/Latest Code/topic_4/html/class_result__coll__graph.dot" -
Tjpg -o "C:/Users/User1/Desktop/Latest Code/topic_4/html/class_result__coll
__graph.jpg" -Tcmapx -o "C:/Users/User1/Desktop/Latest Code/topic_4/html/cl
ass_result__coll__graph.map"`
Running dot for graph 41/43
Running dot for graph 42/43
Running dot for graph 43/43
Patching output file 1/13
Patching output file 2/13
Patching output file 3/13
Patching output file 4/13
Patching output file 5/13
Patching output file 6/13
Patching output file 7/13
Patching output file 8/13
Patching output file 9/13
Patching output file 10/13
Patching output file 11/13
Patching output file 12/13
Patching output file 13/13
lookup cache used 162/65536 hits=755 misses=165
finished...
```

---

Command: `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz2.38\bin\dot" -v`

```
C:\Users\User1\Desktop\Latest Code\topic_4>"C:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz 2.38\bin\dot" -v
dot - graphviz version 2.38.0 (20140413.2041)
libdir = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz2.38\bin"
Activated plugin library: gvplugin_dot_layout.dll
Using layout: dot:dot_layout
Activated plugin library: gvplugin_core.dll
Using render: dot:core
Using device: dot:dot:core
The plugin configuration file:
        C:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz2.38\bin\config6
                was successfully loaded.
    render      :  cairo dot fig gd gdiplus map pic pov ps svg tk vml vrml xdot
    layout      :  circo dot fdp neato nop nop1 nop2 osage patchwork sfdp twopi
    textlayout  :  textlayout
    device      :  bmp canon cmap cmapx cmapx_np dot emf emfplus eps fig gd gd2
gif gv imap imap_np ismap jpe jpeg jpg metafile pdf pic plain plain-ext png pov
ps ps2 svg svgz tif tiff tk vml vmlz vrml wbmp xdot xdot1.2 xdot1.4
    loadimage   :  (lib) bmp eps gd gd2 gif jpe jpeg jpg png ps svg
```

Comment: Which version of doxygen? Try a full qualified path (like: `"C:Program Files (x86)/Graphviz2.38/bin")`, most likely dot is run from another path than you think it is. When you have `dot` in the `PATH` you can also leave the `DOT_PATH` empty.

Comment: Hi @albert, I tried putting the full qualified path and the UML is still not being generated. My version of doxygen is `1.8.17`, and I'm on Windows 7. May I know which is the `PATH` value you are referring to?

Comment: With `PATH` the system path is meant in the system environment. I do see the uml diagram in the class description. Please try to rerun after you have removed the html output directory and do the rerun with `doxygen -d extcmd`. You provided part of your donfiguration file better is to share the output of the command `doxygen -x Doxyfile`

Comment: @albert added in :) `doxygen -x Doxyfile`

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. What is the output of the other commands I requested. Also important is what is the result of `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz2.38\bin\dot" -v`, this will hang but you can terminate it wit ^C.

Comment: I have added `doxygen -d extcmd` output in the source code directory in my post.

Comment: Am running `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz2.38\bin\dot" -v` now...

Comment: Are you sure that yor input path is correct seen the warning: `warning: tag INPUT: input source 'C:/Users/User1/Desktop/Latest Code/topic_4/' does not exist`

Comment: Added in `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz2.38\bin\dot" -v` command output. Let me verify my input source.

Comment: Omg the command `doxygen -d extcmd` actually worked! I have graphs for each individual classes now. But I am unable to locate a full graph which comprises of all of them. Is there a particular section in the `html` page where it consolidates all the classes together into a full UML diagram? p.s. i have also edited my the output of command `doxygen -d extcmd`

Comment: NO there is no "consolidated" output just information per class.

Comment: Ah I see... Thank you @albert for your help man !